# Display an image in HTML that has been retrieved from a database

Tags: java, html, json

I am trying to display an image in HTML that I have read from a database using java. I have tried a few ways which I left in commented out so you can see what I have tried. I have read a number of similar issues; however, none seem to do exactly what I am trying. The result of my current code is that the image is not displayed.

My code is:

Server side JAVA to extract the image from the database:

```
public static Captcha randomCaptcha() {
    //Get connection
    MySQLConnection.getConnection();

    Captcha captcha = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    String imageString = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    // Create connection/statement variables outside of try block
    Connection c = null;

    String selectQry = ("SELECT captcha_id, captcha_code " +
              "FROM at_captcha " +
              "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;");

    try {
        // Get Connection and Statement from DataSource
        c = ds.getConnection();
        ps = c.prepareStatement(selectQry);

        try {

            // Get result set
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                imageString = getCaptchaImageData(result.getString("captcha_id"));
                captcha = new Captcha(
                        result.getString("captcha_id"),
                        imageString, 
                        result.getString("captcha_code"));
            }

            // Clean up
            ps.close();
            c.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SQLException in randomCaptcha: " + se.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Errors occurred in randomCaptcha: " + e.toString());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("SQLException in randomCaptcha: " + e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        // Ensure connection is closed and returned to the pool, even if errors occur.
        try {
            if(ps != null) ps.close();
            if(c != null) c.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in randomCaptcha: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    // Done
    return captcha;
}

public static String getCaptchaImageData(String id){
    //Get connection
    MySQLConnection.getConnection();

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String imageDataString = null;
    // Create connection/statement variables outside of try block
    Connection c = null;

    String selectQry = ("SELECT captcha_image " +
              "FROM at_captcha " + 
              "WHERE captcha_id = ?;");

    try {
        // Get Connection and Statement from DataSource
        c = ds.getConnection();
        ps = c.prepareStatement(selectQry);

        try {
            // Read in the image from the database.

            ps.setString(1, id);

            // Get result set
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                java.sql.Blob imageBlob = result.getBlob(1);
                byte[] imageData = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob.length());

                //Convert Image byte array into Base64 String
                imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);
                imageDataString = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageDataString;
            }

            // Clean up
            ps.close();
            c.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SQLException in getCaptchaImageData: " + se.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Errors occurred in getCaptchaImageData: " + e.toString());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("SQLException in getCaptchaImageData: " + e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        // Ensure connection is closed and returned to the pool, even if errors occur.
        try {
            if(ps != null) ps.close();
            if(c != null) c.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in getCaptchaImageData: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    // Done
    return imageDataString;
}
```

Client side JAVA that calls the server side and then passes the image back:

```
@WebServlet("/CaptchaView")
public class CaptchaView extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Find a random Captcha   
    Captcha aCaptcha = MySQLConnection.randomCaptcha();

    //Store the selected Captcha ID for later use
    MySQLConnection.setViewDataCaptchaID(aCaptcha.getCaptchaId());

    String json = new Gson().toJson(aCaptcha.getCaptchaImage());
    //response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.resetBuffer();
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
}
```

My JSON calls the java and then imbeds the image in the html:

```
$('#selectState').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CaptchaView",
        cache: false,
        data: $(selectState).serialize(),
        success: function(data1a){
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data1a);
        }
    }).done(function(responseJson1a) {
        var byte[] img = Base64.decode(responseJson1a, Base64.DEFAULT);
//      var img = new Image(esponseJson1a);
        dataType: "json",
        //$("#captureDisplay").find("image").remove();
        // JSON response to populate the image

//      $("#img-container").img.src = img;
//      $("#img-container").img.setAttribute("class", "banner-img");
//      $("#img-container").img.setAttribute("alt", "effy");
//      $("#img-container").document.getElementById("img-container").appendChild(img);

        $('<img src').object(img).appendTo($("#img-container"));

    });
});
```

My HTML this is where I want to display the image:

```
<div class="input-group" id="img-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Is storing an image in a SQL database best practice? I've heard it's not. You should store the location of the file in your database (local or on internet) and retrieve the file maybe using one of the stream classes in Java's file handling APIs...

Answer (score 0):

Detailed instructions:

Get a random Captcha:

```
        public static Captcha randomCaptcha() {
        //Get connection
        MySQLConnection.getConnection();

        Captcha captcha = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
        String imageString = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        // Create connection/statement variables outside of try block
        Connection c = null;

        String selectQry = ("SELECT captcha_id, captcha_code " +
                  "FROM at_captcha " +
                  "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;");

        try {
            // Get Connection and Statement from DataSource
            c = ds.getConnection();
            ps = c.prepareStatement(selectQry);

            try {

                // Get result set
                ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

                while (result.next()) {
                    imageString = getCaptchaImageData(result.getString("captcha_id"));
                    captcha = new Captcha(
                            result.getString("captcha_id"),
                            imageString, 
                            result.getString("captcha_code"));
                }

                // Clean up
                ps.close();
                c.close();

            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println("SQLException in randomCaptcha: " + se.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Errors occurred in randomCaptcha: " + e.toString());
            }

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println("SQLException in randomCaptcha: " + e1.toString());
            e1.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            // Ensure connection is closed and returned to the pool, even if errors occur.
            // This is *very* important if using a connection pool, because after all the
            // connections are used, the application will hang on getConnection(), waiting
            // for a connection to become available.
            // Any errors from the following closes are just ignored.  The main thing is
            // that we have definitely closed the connection.
            try {
                if(ps != null) ps.close();
                if(c != null) c.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in randomCaptcha: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Done
        return captcha;
    }

        public static String getCaptchaName(String captchaID) {
        //Get connection
        MySQLConnection.getConnection();

        String captchaName = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        // Create connection/statement variables outside of try block
        Connection c = null;

        String selectQry = ("SELECT captcha_code " +
                  "FROM at_captcha " +
                  "WHERE captcha_id = ?");

        try {
            // Get Connection and Statement from DataSource
            c = ds.getConnection();
            ps = c.prepareStatement(selectQry);

            try {
                ps.setString(1, captchaID);

                // Get result set
                ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

                while (result.next()) {
                    captchaName = result.getString("captcha_code");
                  }

                // Clean up
                ps.close();
                c.close();

            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println("SQLException in getCaptchaName: " + se.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Errors occurred in getCaptchaName: " + e.toString());
            }

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println("SQLException in getCaptchaName: " + e1.toString());
            e1.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            // Ensure connection is closed and returned to the pool, even if errors occur.
            // This is *very* important if using a connection pool, because after all the
            // connections are used, the application will hang on getConnection(), waiting
            // for a connection to become available.
            // Any errors from the following closes are just ignored.  The main thing is
            // that we have definitely closed the connection.
            try {
                if(ps != null) ps.close();
                if(c != null) c.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in getCaptchaName: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Done
        return captchaName;
    }
```

Java:

```
@WebServlet("/CaptchaView")
public class CaptchaView extends HttpServlet implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Find a random Captcha   
        Captcha aCaptcha = MySQLConnection.randomCaptcha();

        //Store the selected Captcha ID for later use
        MySQLConnection.setViewDataCaptchaID(aCaptcha.getCaptchaId());

        String json = aCaptcha.getCaptchaImage();
        json = "<img src=" + json + " width='250' alt='captcha image' >";
        //response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.resetBuffer();
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CaptchaView",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data1a){
            //$('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data1a);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#selectState").focus();
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('An error occured getting the Captcha image');
        }
    }).done(function(responseJson1a) {
        //alert($(responseJson1a).val());
        //alert($(responseJson1a));
        dataType: "json";
        $("#img-container").find("img").remove();
        // JSON response to populate the image
        $(responseJson1a).appendTo($("#img-container"));

    });
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Place for Captcha image -->
<div class="input-group" id="img-container">
</div>
```